# Deployer user does not have Access to the file

Tags: deployment, tfs, msbuild, ms-release-management

I Try to deploy a application using Microsoft Release Management for Visual Studio or better known as "InRelease". But i face unexpected Problems using the MSI-Deployer.

The deployment fails with the flowing error:

```
Setup.msi       XXX139W8    10/1/2014 11:19:18 AM   00:00:00    Package location '\\Server\drop\Application\Build_20140930.5\Setup.msi' does not exist or Deployer user does not have access.           Failed
```

First suggestion(incorrect Path) is not the case, i double checked that.
So why does my Deployer user not have access to my server? And how to fix that?

I tried out running the DeploymentAgent as Administrator, as Local Service adding XXX139W8$ permissions to the drop folder, running as domain user with admin rights on the drop folder.

Sadly the deployment agent is totally unreachable or the error mentioned above shows up.
Here are some system specs:

TFS and RM Server run on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server Express 2012 Installed.
The client i am Working on uses the Release Management Client for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
The Target Machine is a Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this Problem.

The cause was that i specified a File as Package (quite confusing if you try to deploy a single msi file) but the Component should only specify a Folder "Package".

The deployment agent fails to access the Folder (Setup.msi) and fails with the error i showed above.
Then i wasted hours in trying to fix my access problem, because if i enter the "Package location" everything worked fine._.

Answer (score 1):

The deployer user is defined in the MS Deployment Service, ensure that this account has access to your Drop folder. I give the **domain\EVERYONE**  account read access to the drop folder so that anyone can read the data

[image: Deployment Service Configuration]

Comment: for test purposes i used my domain user account to try it out. But sadly the Problem remains (my domain user has full access to the dropfolder)

Comment: on your target machine is there anything being copied in to c:\users\deploymentuser\appdata\local\Temp\ReleaseManagement?

Comment: No there is no folder ReleaseManagement

Comment: ok, so if you log on to the target machine, with your account, can you then access the drop folder?

Comment: If i log into the target machine using the DeploymentAccount (in my case just my account) and copy the path that is not available from my error message into the command line, than the target msi is installed on the target machine

Comment: hmm, struggling...  have you followed the instructions here?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn593699.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62252/discussion-between-console-and-just-tfs).